# D3D output filpped and rotated

Tags: winapi, direct3d

I am trying to get a D3D capture using ID3D11DeviceContext::Map() function.
But the output is flipped and rotated. 
Is this the default behavior? What is the simplest/efficient way to fix this?

```
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE desc;
    hr = context->Map(pRes, subres , D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &desc);

    // use desc.pData

    context->Unmap(target, subres);
```

Thanks

Comment: you should show us how did you use desc.pData.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine.  More than likely you're simply interpreting the resulting data incorrectly.  Texture data starts at the top-left and goes right, then down.  For example the layout of a 4x2 texture looks like this:

```
[0][1][2][3]
[4][5][6][7]
```

Alternatively, the source texture may indeed be flipped and rotated, and is simply being corrected elsewhere in the pipeline (e.g. by rotating in the vertex shader).